# how to get different id values using keyup in jquery function

Tags: php, html, jquery

```
$(document).keyup(function(e){
         var idd = $(".hidd").val();// Here i can't get the correct value of "class hidd" and always get value 1

         var sss = ".comment_tarea" + idd;
          $tArea = $(sss);
          alert(sss);
        if ($tArea.is(":focus") && e.keyCode == 13) {
        var t = $tArea.val();  
    }  
     }); 
        $id1=0;
     while(...){
                $id1++;
        <form >
          <?  $t =$id1; $comment_tarea = "comment_tarea".$t; 
              echo("comment");
              echo($comment_tarea);
          ?>
        <textarea class="<? echo $comment_tarea; ?>" name="tarea"></textarea>
    <input type="hidden" class="hidd" value="<?php  echo htmlspecialchars($id1); ?>" />
        </form>
```

}

In the Jquery function, there is always value 1 in variable idd of class "hidd" for all textarea that means all class of $comment_tarea such as "comment_trea1", "comment_trea2", "comment_trea3", "comment_trea4",.......ans so on.
Here the textarea input value is change by $id1 which is unique.
How can get the correct idd value means get idd=1 for "comment_trea1",get idd=2 for "comment_trea2", get idd=3 for "comment_trea3" and so on...
pls help .

Comment: Check the rendered HTML (View Source). What value is in the hidden input?

Comment: Hidden input value are change means I get the correct value in hidden input.The value of hidden input is increment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `val()` with the selector and it will return value of element at zero index always. To get the value of element at `one` index if exists you can use `$(".hidd").eq(1).val();`

You better bind the `keyup` with your text area instead of binding with document. AS you are generating forms in loop and each loop iteration generates textarea with hidden field. You can `relate` the hidden field with the form `enclosing` textarea.

```
$("textarea[name=tarea]").keyup(function(e){
     var idd = $(this).closest('form').find('.hidd').val();
      //your code
}
```

Comment: `.hidd` is the hidden input. It doesn't get keyups.

Answer (score 2):

.val() returns only the value of the first matched element.

What you need to do is call .val() on every matched element:

```
$(".hidd").each(function() {
  alert($(this).val());
});
```